# Expo notification doesnt fire method when app is killed/closed

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

im using react native expo and push notification works fine when app is running or in background but with the app is close. it doesnt call the method to handle the notification. I need to redirect to detail page. I tried to use function compoents and class components, tried to migrade to legacy notification and the new one.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {
    Image, ScrollView,
    StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, Platform,
    View, Linking,

} from 'react-native';
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";


const HomeScreen = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
        notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(notification => {
        
            const {request, date} = notification ||{}
            const {content} = request ||{}
            const {data} = content ||{}
            const {annKey,type} = data ||{}
           
            if(annKey) {
              //  navigation.navigate('Detail', {annKey,  updateFeed: true, onSelect},)
            }
         

        });


        responseListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(response => {
           

            const {notification} = response ||{}
            console.log(notification);
            const {request, date} = notification ||{}
            const {content} = request ||{}
            const {data} = content ||{}
            const {annKey, type} = data ||{}


            if(annKey){
               navigation.navigate('Detail', {annKey,  updateFeed: true, onSelect},)
            }

          
        });

        return () => {
            Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener);
            Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener);
        };
    }, []);

}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the `useEffect()` get called too late after the app has finished initializing. Therefore the listener is not added before the system has abandoned the notification, and the handler not called.

Fortunately, since you are using the new `expo-notifications` library, it introduced the `useLastNotificationResponse()` React hook. It can replace the `addNotificationResponseReceivedListener()` listener and returns the last notification the user interacted with (i.e. tap). It can be safely used in a `useEffect()` hook.

You can find the documentation here : https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#uselastnotificationresponse-undefined--notificationresponse--null

Here is how to use it (it's better to implement it on your root component):

```js
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';

export default function App() {
  const lastNotificationResponse = Notifications.useLastNotificationResponse();
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (
      lastNotificationResponse &&
      lastNotificationResponse.notification.request.content.data['someDataToCheck'] &&
      lastNotificationResponse.actionIdentifier === Notifications.DEFAULT_ACTION_IDENTIFIER
    ) {
      // navigate to your desired screen
    }
  }, [lastNotificationResponse]);

  return (
    /*
     * your app
     */
  );
}
```

Comment: Including this at the top of App.js finally fixed the issue for my for when the app is killed, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add this to your app.json file:

```
    "android": {
      "useNextNotificationsApi": true,
    },
```